# Loading someone else's .rdata file, can't access the data

Tags: r, load

My professor has sent me an .rdata file and wants me to do some analysis on the contents. Although I'm decent with R, I've never saved my work in .rdata files, and consequently haven't ever worked with them.

When I try to load the file, it looks like it's working:

```
> load('/home/swansone/Desktop/anes.rdata')
> ls()
[1] "25383-0001-Data"
```

But I can't seem to get at the data:

```
> names("25383-0001-Data")
NULL
```

I know that there is data in the .rdata file (it's 13 MB, there's definitely a lot in there) Am I doing something wrong? I'm at a loss.

Edit:

I should note, I've also tried not using quotes:

```
> names(25383-0001-Data)
Error: object "Data" not found
```

And renaming:

```
> ls()[1] <- 'nes'
Error in ls()[1] <- "nes" : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Comment: I've tried no quotes, see edit.

Comment: you can also use get: aReasonableName <- get("25383-0001-Data")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're going to run into a lot of issues with an object that doesn't begin with a letter or . and a letter (as mentioned in [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc)).

Use backticks to access this object (the "Names and Identifiers" section of `` help("`") `` explains why this works) and assign the object to a new, syntactically validly named object.

```
Data <- `25383-0001-Data`
```

Comment: Well, _I_ would never name a variable like that, as I've read the introduction. Unfortunately, this wasn't my data, and An Introduction to R doesn't mention using backticks. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Wilduck: I didn't intend to imply that you named the variable that way.  I also linked to the manual as a reference, not a suggestion that you hadn't read it.  Cheers.

Comment: No hard feelings, I actually do appreciate the response. I think I made that comment for the same reason you included the link. For anyone else who happens to read this page :).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it has to do with the unusual use of dashes in the name and backquotes work:

```
names(`25383-0001-Data`)
```

---

### Edit:

More for reference (since Joshua already answered the main question perfectly), you can also reassign an object from `ls()` (what Wilduck tried in the question) using `get()`. This might be useful if the object of the name contains very weird characters:

```
foo <- 1:5
bar <- get(ls()[1])
bar
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

This of course requires the index of `foo` in `ls()` to be `[1]`, but looking up the index of the required object is not too hard.

Comment: It's not just the dashes.  Names should start with a letter or a `.` and a letter and can only contain letters, `.`, and `_`.

Comment: Ah yes of course. Looking back it is actually very logical why it wouldn't work without the backticks. funny how you can read the `-` sign as dash in a character rather than a minus sign if your mind is set on it being an objectname :)